# Jenkins Declarative pipeline issue- unable to resolve class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to run below Declarative Pipeline

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            echo 'Hello World'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I got the below error

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
jar:file:/home/durgaprasad/.jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 29: unable to resolve class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings
 @ line 29, column 1.
   import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings
   ^
```

below is the Exception stack trace

```
1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:958)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:250)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.recompile(GroovyClassLoader.java:766)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:718)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$TimingLoader.loadClass(CpsGroovyShell.java:170)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelStepLoader.getValue(ModelStepLoader.java:60)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note: 
I am using the following versions
    Jenkins ver. 2.163 , Pipeline 2.6 , pipeline: Declarative plugin 1.4.0 . 
    according to the documentation this declarative pipeline should work with Pipline 2.5.
    https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/
    Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: You're probably missing the findbugs-annotations JAR. However, Jenkins 2.163 is a rather outdated version. I suggest a full Jenkins update before any other action.

Comment: I also faced the similar problem and it was fixed after just upgrading plugins.